# input text box width different in chrome vs all other browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, input, width

I have A LOT of input text boxes on a site I am creating with very specific width's in pixels.

The width of the boxes are all the same in Safari and Firefox but in Chrome, they are off by a few pixels fewer. Does anyone know why this happens or what would be causing this?

EDIT: I use Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 as well

EDIT #2: It looks like Tamil Selvan's box-sizing did the trick. It just really messed up all my heights of other div boxes that I've made. Looks like I'm just going to have to spend some time to fix that. Thanks!!

```
input {
  padding:3px;
  height:8px;
  outline: 0;
  border:0;
  border-radius:3px;
}
```

Comment: try `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: I tried this, but it makes all my boxes smaller?

Comment: Where in that CSS are you defining the "specific width"? You might consider normalize.css rather than a generic reset.

Comment: I'm defining it in the html of  my input box <input style="width:xxx" />

Comment: Check edit #2, Thanks Tamil!

Comment: @bryan Can you post an answer to this question rather than editing it? That way, people can see it's solved.

Comment: @Mr-Lister I can't answer my own question until 8 hours after I ask it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Tamil Selvan's box-sizing did some of the trick.

I added the following to really fix some of the problems I was having with the box's not being the same:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

However, I have found that letter-spacing is also an issue. Safari and chrome's letter spacing is off slightly too and I am trying to figure out how to fix this as well.

[Letter Spacing Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BSY3.png)

```
font-family: 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
```